# Rust - importing root file to a module

Tags: rust

I'm starting to learn Rust and I stumbled into a weird import problem. I have an example directory structure:

```
example_mod
    file1.rs
example_mod.rs
file2.rs
```

I would like to import the contents of file2.rs into example_mod.rs. I tried:

```
use crate::file2;
use super::file2;
use file2;
```

And each time I get the `use of undeclared type or module file2` error. How such sibling module should be imported?

Comment: Is `pub mod file2` in `lib.rs`?

Comment: @Kellen tried it, but the error persists.

Answer (score 2):

Beginning new things is fun (and can be difficult). Now, your description of the problem you are having makes helping you kind of difficult. But, when you're starting out it can be hard to help yourself help-yourself. Check out how to create a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Also check out what the [Rust Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-00-managing-growing-projects-with-packages-crates-and-modules.html) says about `crate`s, modules, paths, and `use`. And, join the [Rust Community](https://users.rust-lang.org/) if you want rust-specific help.

Okay, I'm making some assumptions about your code structure because you've left out a good deal of information.

So, if you run `cargo new app` you'll end up with a project folder containing a `src/` directory.

I've added some files/directories and the result looks like this:

```
src/
├── core                    # a directory/folder
│   ├── mod.rs        
│   └── some_other_code.rs  # a "file"
├── main.rs                 
└── some_code.rs            # another "file"
```

In `main.rs`:

```rust
/// Module declarations.
mod core;
mod some_code;

/// Bring paths into scope with the `use`
/// keyword keyword.
use self::some_code::hello;
// The above can also be written as:
// use some_code::hello;
// why?

/// An absolute path starts from a crate root by
/// using a crate name or a literal `crate`.
use crate::core::greeting;

const JUPITER: &str = "jupiter";

fn main() {
    hello();
    greeting();

    // A relative path starts from the current
    // module and uses self, super, or an identifier
    // in the current module.
    use self::another_mod;
    // You can also check if the following would work:
    // use crate::another_mod;
    // Or even,
    // use another_mod;
    // why?
    another_mod::jupiter();
}

mod another_mod {
    use super::*;

    pub fn jupiter() {
        println!("hello, {}!", JUPITER);
    }
}
```

In `some_code.rs`:

```rust
pub fn hello() {
    println!("mars");
}
```

In `core/mod.rs`:

```rust
/// Module declaration.
pub mod some_other_code;

/// Re-exporting the greeting function.
pub use some_other_code::greeting;
```

In `core/some_other_code.rs`:

```rust
use crate::some_code;

pub fn greeting() {
    println!("hello");
    some_code::hello();
}
```

To give you an idea of what you'll find in the **Rust Book**:

> Packages: A Cargo feature that lets you build, test, and share crates
>
> Crates: A tree of modules that produces a library or executable
>
> Modules and use: Let you control the organization, scope, and privacy of paths
>
> Paths: A way of naming an item, such as a struct, function, or module

And,

> `src/main.rs` and `src/lib.rs` are called **crate roots**. The reason for their name is that the contents of either of these two files **form a module named crate at the root of the crate’s module structure**, known as the module tree.

Comment: I've been looking for the exact example as in my case in the book, but can't find it. Your examples are not quite the same and I suspect this might be the problem. Note that you're using mod.rs and not a named module file in src. Also, you're not importing some_code in this file.

Comment: @krojew The reason for the difference is that @eric is using the older Rust 2015 module naming. `mod.rs` in `src/core` is the equivalent to `src/core.rs` in Rust 2018

Answer (score -2):

I've been through the book on this and ran that gamut.  I personally don't like saying the following.

```
// *** main.rs
mod some_mod
use crate::some_mod::some_fn;

//rather just if you're going to
mod some_mod 
use some_mod:some_fn;

//even further recall the binary name can see every mod that lives in main and lib
//so with the above you could move the mod to lib and keep main clean of mod
// *** lib.rs
pub mod some_mod 
      // then back in main just do
      use rust_book::some_mod::some_fn;

// *** cargo.toml

[package]
name = "rust_book"

// Also keep in mind mods outside of lib will not be in cargo doc
```